# Gitlab ci yml syntax error

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to add a gitlab-ci.yml to my project but I get the following error:

`Error: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 10 column 15`

```
before-script:
    - bash ci/install.sh > /dev/null

cache:
    paths:
    - vendor/

test:5.6:
    image: php:5.6
        script: 
        - vendor/bin/codecept run

test:7.0:
    image: php:7.0
        script: 
        - vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a play with the linter I found the correct syntax is:

```
before_script:
- bash ci/install.sh > /dev/null

test:5.6:
  image: php:5.6

  script:
  - vendor/bin/codecept run

test:7.0:
  image: php:7.0

  script:
  - vendor/bin/codecept run
```